# Unable to do http request to sibling docker containers in local environment

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose

### **UPDATE:**

I found three problems in my code

1. The url in the **CoreWebApi:ValuesController.cs:** was wrong:
   [image]
2. The port 5002 of Data Api project pointed to the non-SSL and also removed SSL URLs from both Data API and Web API projects

**docker-compose.development.yml: core-data-api-service:**
[image]

**docker-compose.development.yml: core-web-api-service:**
[image]

3. Removed **app.UseHttpsRedirection();** from the startup.cs files of both the projects.

Now I am able to make a container to container HTTP call on the non-ssl ports.

However, I am still not able to make https calls on the ssl ports.

If I change url in the CoreWebApi>ValuesController.cs to:

```
https://core-data-api-service:5003/api/values
```

Then I get the following error:
[image]

---

I have two basic asp.net core web API apps: 1. CoreWebApi 2. CoreDataApi.

I am running both apps in two separate containers in my local Windows 10 host.

You can find complete code in [this git repo](https://github.com/SaurabhLpRocks/multi-container-app-demo).

I am unable to make an HTTP call from the containerized CoreWebApi app to the containerized CoreDataApi app. Getting following exception in CoreWebApi app:
[image]

**The localhost URLs for both the apps are:**

1. CoreWebApi  - http://localhost:5000 & https://localhost:5001
2. CoreDataApi - http://localhost:5002 & https://localhost:5003

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

**CoreWebApi:ValuesController.cs:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>> Get () {
            try {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync ("http://core-web-api-service:5002/api/values");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode ();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

                Console.WriteLine (response.StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine ("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-------Success--------XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
            } catch (HttpRequestException e) {
                Console.WriteLine ("\nException Caught!");
                Console.WriteLine ("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine ("StackTrace :{0} ", e.StackTrace);
            }
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
```

both containers are using the same network which is created by the name of root folder vscode-workflow:
[image]

**./vscode-workflow/CoreWebApi/.docker/development.dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS base
WORKDIR /src

# Copy only the project file.
# We copied only the project file and not the complete source code
# to leverage the docker's caching capabilities thereby optimizing up the build time.
COPY ["CoreWebApi.csproj", "./"]

# Restore the packages
RUN dotnet restore "./CoreWebApi.csproj"

# Copy the source code to the /src directory
COPY . .

RUN update-ca-certificates

# Expose ports 5000 & 5001 as our app will run on these ports
EXPOSE 5000 5001
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "watch", "--project=CoreWebApi.csproj", "run"]
```

**./vscode-workflow/docker-compose.development.yml:**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  core-web-api-service:
    image: core.web.api.dev.image
    container_name: core.web.api.dev.container
    build:
      args:
        buildconfig: Debug
      context: ./CoreWebApi
      dockerfile: .docker/development.dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

      # Set the certificate env variables (We copied certificate from host to below location. See volumes)
      - Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/root/.dotnet/https/aspnetcore-cert.pfx
      - Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=yourpassword

      # The .net core base image used in the docker file, runs the app on port 80 by default
      # Force it to run on ports 5000 & 5001
      # Also we are specifying 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost
      # as the app crashes inside docker when used localhost.
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5000/;https://0.0.0.0:5001
      - DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
      - 5001:5001
    volumes:
      # Map the certificate from host to the container
      - 'c:/cert/:/root/.dotnet/https'
      - 'c:/cert/:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates'
      - './CoreWebApi/:/src'

  core-data-api-service:
    image: core.data.api.dev.image
    container_name: core.data.api.dev.container
    build:
      args:
        buildconfig: Debug
      context: ./CoreDataApi
      dockerfile: .docker/development.dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

      # Set the certificate env variables (We copied certificate from host to below location. See volumes)
      - Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/root/.dotnet/https/aspnetcore-cert.pfx
      - Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=yourpassword

      # The .net core base image used in the docker file, runs the app on port 80 by default
      # Force it to run on ports 5000 & 5001
      # Also we are specifying 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost
      # as the app crashes inside docker when used localhost.
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5003/;https://0.0.0.0:5002
      - DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true
    ports:
      - 5002:5002
      - 5003:5003
    volumes:
      # Map the certificate from host to the container
      - 'c:/cert/:/root/.dotnet/https'
      - 'c:/cert/:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates'
      - './CoreDataApi/:/src'
```

Comment: Is the HTTP call from CoreWebApi to CoreDataApi using localhost or the service/container name... and are you using http or https?

Comment: Question updated.